# How to target square bracket directive variable CSS style

Tags: css, angular

I was implementing the following directive from https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/786#issuecomment-418655803. But I wasn't able to target the element[directive] to style.

For a simple attribute you can target like the following example from [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_width_inputfocus):

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
```

But how to target square bracket wrapping attribute? Example:

```css
test[di=true] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<test [di]="true">test</test>
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Can you not assign a css class and target that way?

Comment: @Morpheus I was going to make it a global style. Since I was declare the directive in shared module, so it could be used easily. I would consider to add a custom variable each component just for the NgClass to be checking the directive boolean value. If there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't do that. You should instead use ngClass:

`<test [ngClass]="{'tested-class': true}">test</test>`

```
test.tested-class {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add, remove class or even change the class.

```
<a[ngClass]="{'tested-class': condition }">testing</a>

 Or   
<a[ngClass]="[condition? 'tested-class-a': 'tested-class-b any-other']">testing</a>
```